# ASP.NET MVC one of the forms dont get validation messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

My problem is this: I have created a view in which I want to be able to remove and add new identity roles. For that I created two forms that call two different actions. I have created a big model which consists of smaller models which are bound by the forms to the actions. Everything works as intended, models get bound properly, data is there and proper actions are executed as they should.

Don't get me wrong, I understand those are separate forms and I know they will never show validation messages both at the same time because only one form can be posted at a time. The problem is that when I click submit on the `CreateNewRole` form, the validation message is there, but when I click submit on the `RemoveRoles` action, I don't get any validation messages and no validation classes are applied to the html elements, there is the usual "field-validation-valid" and no "field-validation-error" class in it while its perfectly present in `CreateNewRole`.

Why does validation work on the first form but not on the second form? I cant find any difference in how i made those two forms, am i not noticing something?

When I debug modelstate of the `RemoveRoles` action, the error is there, but somehow the view isn't getting informed of it.

View

```
@model Models.ViewModels.RolePanelViewModel    
@using Extensions

<h2>Role Panel</h2>

<article>
    <div class="admin-panel-flex-container">
        <div class="form-container">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewRole", "Administrator"))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(l => l.NewRoleRolePanelViewModel.NewIdentityRole.Name)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.NewRoleRolePanelViewModel.NewIdentityRole.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.NewRoleRolePanelViewModel.NewIdentityRole.Name)
                    <button type="submit">Dodaj role</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

        <div class="form-container">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveRoles", "Administrator"))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(l => l.ListRolePanelViewModel.SelectedIdentityRoles)
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(l => l.ListRolePanelViewModel.SelectedIdentityRoles, @Model.ListRolePanelViewModel.IdentityRolesSelectListItems)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.ListRolePanelViewModel.SelectedIdentityRoles)
                    <button type="submit">Skasuj wybrane</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

    </div>
</article>
```

Models

```
public class RolePanelViewModel
{
    public ListRolePanelViewModel ListRolePanelViewModel { get; set; }
    public NewRoleRolePanelViewModel NewRoleRolePanelViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class ListRolePanelViewModel
{
    public List<IdentityRoleDTO> IdentityRoles { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> IdentityRolesSelectListItems { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Należy wybrać przynajmniej jedną pozycję z listy")]
    public List<string> SelectedIdentityRoles { get; set; }        
}

public class NewRoleRolePanelViewModel
{
    public IdentityRoleDTO NewIdentityRole { get; set; }
}
public class IdentityRoleDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nowa rola musi mieć nazwę")]
    [MinLength(5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<IdentityUserRole> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Actions

```
public ActionResult OpenRolePanel()
{
    var roles = _context.Roles.ToList();
    var viewModel = new RolePanelViewModel
    {
        ListRolePanelViewModel = new ListRolePanelViewModel
        {
            IdentityRolesSelectListItems = GetSelectListItems(roles,
                (a) => new SelectListItem {Value = a.Id.ToString(), Selected = false, Text = a.Name})

        },
        NewRoleRolePanelViewModel = new NewRoleRolePanelViewModel()

    };
    return View("RolePanel", viewModel);
} 

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateNewRole(NewRoleRolePanelViewModel newRoleRolePanelViewModel)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var roles = _context.Roles.ToList();
        var viewModel = new RolePanelViewModel
        {
            ListRolePanelViewModel = new ListRolePanelViewModel
            {
                IdentityRolesSelectListItems = GetSelectListItems(roles,
                    (a) => new SelectListItem { Value = a.Id.ToString(), Selected = false, Text = a.Name })

            },
            NewRoleRolePanelViewModel = newRoleRolePanelViewModel
        };
        return View("RolePanel", viewModel);
    }
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext());
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(newRoleRolePanelViewModel.NewIdentityRole.Name));


    return View("RolePanel");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveRoles(ListRolePanelViewModel listRolePanelViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var roles = _context.Roles.ToList();
        var viewModel = new RolePanelViewModel
        {
            ListRolePanelViewModel = listRolePanelViewModel,
            NewRoleRolePanelViewModel = new NewRoleRolePanelViewModel()
        };
        viewModel.ListRolePanelViewModel.IdentityRolesSelectListItems = GetSelectListItems(roles,
            (a) => new SelectListItem {Value = a.Id.ToString(), Selected = false, Text = a.Name});

        return View("RolePanel", viewModel);
    }

    return View("RolePanel");
}
```

Custom method that may be needed if you want to run the code

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems<T>(List<T> dbSetResult, Func<T,SelectListItem> Func)
        {          
            var result = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var item in dbSetResult)
            {
                result.Add(Func(item));
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: try changing "SelectedIdentityRoles" to a string[] instead of list<string>

Comment: Tried it just now, didint work :( 
In my other form where there is just one form on a page i too have a itemlist with List<SelectListItem> and validation messages work in this instance.

Comment: What validation error are you expecting, and in what circumstances?

Comment: I expect ListRolePanelViewModel model to have validation error if i dont pick any item from the list. When i debugg the action i can see in modelstate that there is in fact a validation error and modelstate is not valid which is what i want, but after the view gets rendered the error classes like "field-validation-error" that trigger error css styles and messages dont get passed on to view. But only for the listbox action, for the textbox action everything works fine.

Comment: Not tested, but I suspect the issue is related to the fact that your POST method parameter is not the same model that you use in the view (and the methods should be `public ActionResult RemoveRoles(RolePanelViewModel  model)`

Comment: But i want models to be validated separately. If i do it like you suggested if i try to post just one form i will get modelstate validation errors from not filling in the properties of the other form.

Comment: @XomRng. No you will not - the 'other' property will be `null` and therefore validation will not be executed (because there is nothing to validate)

Comment: Even if the field is "required"?

Comment: You do not have a [Required]` attribute on either the `ListRolePanelViewModel` or `NewRoleRolePanelViewModel` properties (only on properties of those models) therefore they can be `null` (which one or the other will be), and validation is not performed on objects which are `null`

Comment: I have made my POST methods parameter type to RolePanelViewModel, the same as my model in view. But i still dont get any validation. It looks like something unusual broke somewhere.